# Set wallpaper using RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-wallpaper

I need to set an image as wallpaper using `RecyclerView`. In my adapter i'm using this code:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        final GridItem nature = mItems.get(i);
        viewHolder.tvspecies.setText(nature.getName());
        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());

        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("CLick",nature.toString());
                try {
                    wallpaper.setResource(mItems.get(i));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

so onClick i should set the image as wallpaper but under "setResource" word i have this error:

```
The method setResource(int) in the type WallpaperManager is not applicable for the arguments (GridItem)
```

How can i set the item selected from the adapter as wallpaper?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can paste code for GridItem class

Answer (score 0):

The reason your program is not working, the method `setResource(int)` takes in `int` type as a parameter and not `GridItem`type.

Reading more from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setResource(int))

> Change the current system wallpaper to the bitmap in the given
>   resource. The resource is opened as a raw data stream and copied into
>   the wallpaper; it must be a valid PNG or JPEG image.

also make sure your app have permission to set wallpaper in manifest

> This method requires the caller to hold the permission SET_WALLPAPER.